# Trigger splunk alert when received values do not change

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I receive exchange rate from an external web service and I log the response received like below (note both line contain data from a single response):

```
com.test.Currency@366c1a1e[Id=<Null>,Code=<Null>,Feedcode=Gbparslite,Rate=<Null>,Percentaqechangetrigger=<Null>,Bid=93.4269,Offer=93.43987,Mustinvertprice=False], 
com.test.Currency@54acb93a[Id=<Null>,Code=<Null>,Feedcode=Gbphkdlite,Rate=<Null>,Percentaqechangetrigger=<Null>,Bid=10.04629,Offer=10.04763,Mustinvertprice=False],
```

I want to set up an alert which triggers when the last x (x=5) values received did not changed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking to alert when a particular field doesn't change after 5 events, you can try the following.

```
index=data | head 5 | stats dc(Bid) as dv
```

Then alert if dv equals 1. dc(Bid) calculates the number of unique values of Bid, in this case, over the last 5 events. If there is no difference, they will be 1. If there are multiple values, dc(Bid) will be greater than 1

Comment: This works if there is a single `Bid` in response. However in above response there was a single result output. I edited to emphasize this. 
Your solution would work if there was a single `Bid` per response

Comment: Try using _raw instead of any one field, index=data | head 5 | stats dc(_raw) as dv